# Exceldna equivalent for Java

Tags: java, excel-dna

ExcelDNA is a fantastic resource for C# developers - is there anything similar for Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what comes nearest is [XLL4J – Excel Addin Framework for Java](http://xll4j.sourceforge.net/), still Alpha though.

> XLL4J is a framework for developing Microsoft Excel addins (XLLs) in
>   Java. It provides a mechanism for implementing Excel functions in Java
>   and has the following features:
>
> - Easy Java VM management via INI file (refer to table below for details).
> - Two APIs; one low-level and one reflection based for easy implementation.
> - Built-in CSV addin for accessing CSV from filesystem or network.

and of course the linked project [XLLoop – Excel User-Defined Functions in Java, Javascript, Ruby, Python, Erlang](http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/).

> XLLoop is an open source framework for implementing Excel user-defined functions (UDFs) on a centralised server (a function server).

Comment: thanks platzhirsch, I will have a look at both. XLL4J says it is on hold - do you have any idea how long it's been on hold for?

Comment: @user1191840 Version 0.0.2 was uploaded in November 2007, I guess it will stay on hold. XXLoop should be your choice, they have moved to GitHub and commited to the Java project 6 month ago https://github.com/poidasmith/xlloop

Comment: Jinx (https://exceljava.com) is a new solution for this problem. Unlike XLLoop it embeds the JVM in the Excel process and so doesn't require any external process/service to be running.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider running your Java code on the CLR using the [IKVM Java runtime](http://www.ikvm.net/). This will allow you to use [Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) for your Excel integration. I haven't tried it myself, but [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/exceldna/browse_frm/thread/7763a8d215970a26) from a few years ago suggests that it works fine. I'm also happy to help if you run into any issues.

Comment: thanks Govert, I assume that would definitely work, but you would need to write wrappers individually for each function wouldn't you? Also, do you have any idea of the performance of this?

Comment: If you get it to work, the performance should be fine. Whether you need wrappers would depend on how IKVM.NET exposes your code, and whether you already have static methods with friendly signatures. To add Descriptions and other attribute info you need to check how IKVM maps the attributes. But there would be a lot to learn. Another option is to translate the Java code to C# using Sharpen or something.